# replace symfony2 access denied template

Tags: php, symfony, security

Using Symfony2.3.4, PHP5.6.3 and Twig.

See, this is the template used by symfony everytime a user tries to access a `url` and it does not pass the access control set in the `security.yml` file.
All I want is to redirect the user to a template of my creation/choosing.

If I were restricting the user's access in a `PHP` class, sure, I could ask for its role/permissions and decide from there but I want to use the access control I have already set in my `security.yml` file, say like a global `.html.twig` file to replace the one below.

[image: Symfony template]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you see is the debug version of the 'error' page... it should never be used in production ... because it gives away wayy too much information ...

i am assuming you just want to show your users a simple 403 error message ... and not a stack trace of the exception.

so use the url without the app_dev.php ... to see what everyone else will see... not only the devs.

the template lives in 
`vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Resources\views\Exception\error.html.twig`

In the vendors directory under symfony

to replace it copy the file and put it in your app directory

`app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.html.twig`

and change it to something cool...

clear the cache
`php app/console cache:clear -e prod`

you should be good to go... :)

ref [SF Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html)